# Angular Array -- multiple values in one object

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to create an array in AngularJS and filter it by object name but use a function to filter the array but wanted to use multiple values in one object name. This is what i currently have which I'm going for which isn't currently working.

IDEAL solution:

```
{
    name: 'company',
    date: 201202,
    medium: 'digital','web'
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The only way to add more values is to create another object to hold the values.  medium : {name:value, name:value}

Comment: Thats what i thought but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this,

```
{
    name: 'company',
    date: 201202,
    medium: ['digital','web']
    }
```

use medium as an array.  it's impossible to have two values for a property unless it's an array.